# Joi validate presence of a key or another one

Tags: joi

I'm using Joi for http body validation. I want to allow keyA to be present OR a keyB to be present and required but not both. I don't find in documentation what I'm looking for and it seems that a cycling loop appear in my schema.

```
const messageSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  keyA: Joi.when('keyB', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.forbidden(), otherwise: Joi.string().required() }),
  keyB: Joi.when('keyA', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.forbidden(), otherwise: Joi.string().uri().required() }),
});
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Finally found what I was looking for :

```
const messageSchema = Joi.object().keys({
 keyA: Joi.string(),
 keyB: Joi.string().uri(),
}).or('keyA', 'keyB');
```